# Disambiguate the various quoting mechanisms in Julia metaprogramming

Tags: metaprogramming, julia, quoting

Could someone lay out clearly the various quoting mechanisms available for metaprogramming in Julia, and illustrate each one with a minimal example?

So that it is clear which to use in which situation...

As far as I can see there is:

- `:(someExpr; maybeMore)`
- `quote; ...expressions... end;` which is almost the same as the above only with line numbers for debug purposes
- `Expr(:quote, x)` which ([according to @totalverb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3575047/fengyang-wang)) is equivalent to `Meta.quot(x)`
- QuoteNode which ([according to Jeff Bezanson](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/6104#issuecomment-37260078)) *"is only used in the internal AST representation, not by macros. It's **safe to ignore** unless you work on later stages of the compiler."*

Is this list comprehensive?  Am I missing out any alternate representations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`:...` is the default quoting mechanism. It parses an expression and returns the AST.

```
:x == Symbol("x")

:(x + y) == Expr(:call, :+, :x, :y)

:(x; y; z) == Expr(:block, :x, :y, :z)
```

`eval(:<expr>)` should return the same as just `<expr>` (assuming `<expr>` is a valid expression in the current global space)

```
eval(:(1 + 2)) == 1 + 2

eval(:(let x=1; x + 1 end)) == let x=1; x + 1 end
```

---

`quote ... end` is the same as `:(begin ... end)`

---

`Expr(:quote, x)` is used to represent quotes within quotes.

```
Expr(:quote, :(x + y)) == :(:(x + y))

Expr(:quote, Expr(:$, :x)) == :(:($x))
```

---

`QuoteNode(x)` is similar to `Expr(:quote, x)` but it prevents interpolation.

```
eval(Expr(:quote, Expr(:$, 1))) == 1

eval(QuoteNode(Expr(:$, 1))) == Expr(:$, 1)
```

---

Here's a macro using all of them:

```
macro quoted(expression)
    quote
        println("received expression: :(", $(QuoteNode(expression)), ")")
        $(Expr(:quote, expression))
    end
end
```

Usage:

```
julia> x = 1
1

julia> @quoted $x + 1
received expression: :($(Expr(:$, :x)) + 1)
:(1 + 1)

julia> @quoted :(x + 1)
received expression: :($(Expr(:quote, :(x + 1))))
:($(Expr(:quote, :(x + 1))))
```

---

**edit**: `Meta.quot(x)` is indeed the same as `Expr(:quote, x)`. It's undocumented and isn't mentioned anywhere, but it was a conscious addition to the functions exported by `Base` (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/1755) and I haven't seen any plans to deprecate it, so you can use it.